# Print the "keyboard shortcuts

Tags: printing

How do I print the default "keyboard shortcuts"?  Can not find a way to copy-paste or send to the printer.

Answer (score 0):

Use <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Prt Scr</kbd> to save a screenshot to your Pictures folder (usually `~/Pictures`) and then print the resulting image.